# Trying to show YouTube video in web page

Tags: html, youtube

I am trying to show a YouTube video in a web page, but all that comes up is an empty box with a black border where the video should be.  Here is the code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Granada High School Class of 1986 Graduation</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe width="420" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l_fN8LXco2A?autoplay=0">
</iframe> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You'll need to use the "embed" url when displaying in an iframe as shown in the "share" section of a video

Comment: i.e. https://www.youtube.com/embed/l_fN8LXco2A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. This is provided by Youtube when you click share and then embed:

[image]

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/l_fN8LXco2A" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Hope it helps